# How to save to table with EF when detail not known

Tags: entity-framework

I'm trying to build a time management software. I know this type of software already exists but I feel it's a good challenge for my learning

[image]

The problem I have is how I can save a new project item and assign the appropriate resource.

The only 3 tables which matter for this question is the ProjectItem, ResourceDetails and Resource.

When I try to save the ProjectItem, I know all the information required for the ProjectItem table, and I know the ProjectPlanId and the Name for the ResourceDetail, which already exist in the ResourceDetail table.

What I don't know is how to populate the Resource table. Because when I'm trying to save, I can only save ProjectItem and ResourceDetail.

How do I tell the database, through EF 6, to add/update the ResourceId and ProjectItemId to the Resource table?

Comment: this is actually a quite substantial disadvantage of EF; I don't think there is any simple way to achieve what you want. Either you have to keep all related entries (ProjectItem,Resource, ResourceDetail) in your context while modifying (EF should recognize changes in the context and mirror them as Update/Insert calls to the database), or set the FK properties manually.

Comment: What type of EF context are you using? (code first or db first)

Comment: DB first @MikeMazmanyan